# Can't find input box using Selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to locate an input box using python Selenium:

```html
try:
    thisbox = driver.find_element_by_id('tbRepID')

except EC.NoSuchElementException:
    print("Could not locate the Repair ID Box!")
```

Selenium is able to find the first 5 boxes using this same type of code, but for some reason, it raises the "NoSuchElementException" when trying to find the sixth one. I've tried using "find_element_by_name" and "find_element_by_id" with no success.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmJV6.jpg]

```html
                   <table class="gray-border" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="0" width="100%" border="0">
                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td colspan="4">
                                      Part Nbr:<input name="tbPn" type="text" id="tbPn" style="width:112px;">
                                &nbsp;/SN:<input name="tbSn" type="text" id="tbSn" style="width:72px;">
                                &nbsp; or PO Nbr:<input name="tbPOnbr" type="text" id="tbPOnbr" style="width:72px;">
                                &nbsp; or SO Nbr:<input name="tbSOnbr" type="text" id="tbSOnbr" style="width:72px;">
                                &nbsp; or WO Nbr:<input name="tbWOnbr" type="text" id="tbWOnbr" style="width:72px;">
                                &nbsp; or Rep Id:<input name="tbRepId" type="text" id="tbRepId" style="width:56px;">
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                <input type="submit" name="bFind1" value="Find" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;bFind1&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="bFind1">
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                
                            </td>
                        </tr>
```

Comment: what error it is throwing?? can you post your code as well?

Answer (score 0):

Without the error that you get with the sixth one, I can't really know what is the issue.

But by the description and hoping that there are no code errors, the browser could change the DOM for the page. And the driver keeps trying to find the element in the wrong DOM.
I had this issue with some web pages.

The resolution I had for this was in all the interactions with an element using find the element.
In Java: driver.findElement(By.id("id"));

Answer (score 0):

To click the sixth box adjusant to the text **or Rep Id** you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#tbRepId[name='tbRepId']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='tbRepId' and @name='tbRepId']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: I did try using an explicit wait and it didn't seem to make any difference. Since I was able to find it indirectly, I assume the problem isn't that it just didn't have time to load before selenium started looking for it?

Answer (score 0):

Although I couldn't reference the Rep ID input box directly, I was able to reference it indirectly using:

```html
inputBoxes = []
inputBoxes = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("input[type='text']")

# Send repair ID
inputBoxes[5].send_keys('145862')
```